# Install virtualenv on windows without pip

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

In linux, you have the option to install virtualenv from apt-get so you don't have to install pip globally. This helps because you can't install a pip package globally for mistake. In the official documentation, they don't explain how to do that in windows. I found the command: *"python install setup.py"* but even with that I don't know where the virtualenv command is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download the package from pypi.python.org (Source) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv and unpackage it. In a command window, go into the folder and install it:

> c:...\virtualenv-X.X.X> python setup.py install

Then write a virtualenv.bat file inside the folder with this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Install version of virtualenv from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
IF "%1"=="" GOTO ERROR
IF "%1"=="-d" GOTO DELETE
ECHO "creating virtualenv in %1"
python -m virtualenv %1
ECHO "VIRTUALENV CREATED. To activate: %1\Scripts\activate.bat"
GOTO END
:DELETE
IF "%2"=="" GOTO ERROR
IF NOT EXIST "%2\Scripts\activate.bat" GOTO ERROR_FOLDER
rmdir /S/Q %2
GOTO END
:ERROR_FOLDER
ECHO "The directory is not a virtualenv" 
GOTO END
:ERROR 
ECHO "You need to specify the name of the virtualenv"
:END
```

finally add *c:...\virtualenv-X.X.X* to the path configuration in windows. Now you can use wherever you want comand **virtualenv virtual-machine-name** and create and instance of virtualenv. To activate use **Scripts\activate.bat** To delete the virtualenv **virtualenv -d virtual-name-machine**

Maybe there are better solutions but I couldn't find them so I had to do this bat file